# Which way is considered more efficient to compare these variables?

Tags: c#, performance, comparison

I am writing a player controller and I am getting the player movement on two axes (X, Y). The values can roughly be `-1, 0, 1` on each axis. Positive values point UP and to the RIGHT. It is impossible for **both** values to be zero based on a previous check I make.

Based on their combination I want to determine the direction the player is facing. There are eight possible directions for the player to take. I use the `enum`: `FacingDirection`, to pass the direction.

> Example to clarify:
> If `X = 1` and `Y = 0` then the player is moving towards the RIGHT side of the screen.
>
> If `X = -1` and `Y = -1` then the player is moving towards DOWN LEFT corner of the screen.

I have come up with two possible solutions to this problem, but I wish to know which one is more efficient.
Both solutions use `_inputs`, which is a 2D vector, to get the values for `X` and `Y`.

#### Solution A

```
private FacingDirection findMoveDirection() {
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    float testing = _inputs.x;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int temp;
        if (testing != 0) {
            temp = (testing > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            temp = 0;
        }

        if (i < 1) {
            x = temp;
        } else {
            y = temp;
            break;
        }
        testing = _inputs.y;
    }

    int check = x + y;
    switch (check) {
        case 2 : {
            return FacingDirection.UP_RIGHT;
        }
        case -2 : {
            return FacingDirection.DOWN_LEFT;
        }
        case 1 : {
            if (x > 0) {
                return FacingDirection.RIGHT;
            } else {
                return FacingDirection.UP;
            }
        }
        case 0 : {
            if (x > 0) {
                return FacingDirection.DOWN_RIGHT;
            } else {
                return FacingDirection.UP_LEFT;
            }
        }
        case -1 : {
            if (x < 0) {
                return FacingDirection.LEFT;
            } else {
                return FacingDirection.DOWN;
            }
        }
        default : {
            Debug.LogWarning("Something went wrong while determining moving direction. Returning DOWN as moving direction.");
            return FacingDirection.DOWN;
        }
    }
```

#### Solution B

This is a more straight-forward `if/else` approach.

```
private FacingDirection findMoveDirection() {
    float x = _inputs.x, y = _inputs.y;

    if (x != 0) {
        if (x > 0) {
            if (y != 0) {
                if (y > 0) {
                    return FacingDirection.UP_RIGHT;
                } else {
                    return FacingDirection.DOWN_RIGHT;
                }
            } else {
                return FacingDirection.RIGHT;
            }
        } else {
            if (y != 0) {
                if (y > 0) {
                    return FacingDirection.UP_LEFT;
                } else {
                    return FacingDirection.DOWN_LEFT;
                }
            } else {
                return FacingDirection.LEFT;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (y > 0) {
            return FacingDirection.UP;
        } else {
            return FacingDirection.DOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: @MickyD Thanks a lot for letting me know. Should I just delete it in advance in that case?

Comment: Going by the guidelines perhaps yes.  Besides, if you ask on another SE site you might get much more value for your question.    Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine both values into a single one. For instance:

```
int directions = y * 2 + x;
```

It uniquely identifies a direction.
Its allowed values are: `-3` ... `+3`, excluding `0`.
Then you can use it in a `switch` (Solution A without `if`s) or as a dictionary key.

Comment: This is very clever. Would this method work if `float` values were used?

Comment: @Lae Well, using fuzzy compare of values and if source values are discrete and limited too, then yes, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution B** is definitely faster, it does 4 comparisons in the worst case, while solution **A** does 8 comparisons, also in the worst case, just within the for loop.

You can benchmark both methods and verify that. It's always a good idea to actually measure the performance: this code is quite simple but in more complex situations there are factors that are not obvious (ie. CPU caching effect when dealing with many objects in memory).

Comment: _"Solution B is definitely faster"_ - do you have actual metrics for that or are you guessing? This is why questions like this are bad for SO, it leads to unfounded claims in answers. _"You can benchmark both methods and verify that"_ - the onus is on you actually.    B by my count has at least 7 compares not _"4"_ due to the `if` statements each one adding to cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: I stated my metrics. My conclusion is based on the assumption that the compiler does a reasonable job. If you want to be pedantic, a compiler could do a terrible job in either of the two solutions, so it's not possible to prove which one performs better without testing with that exact compiler. But, pragmatically speaking, I believe my answer is sensible.

You mentioned cyclomatic complexity, but I don't see how that affects execution speed. There are many execution paths, but only 4 comparisons will execute in the worst case.

Comment: So guessing then.  Because the OP's question wasn't _constructive subjective_ whereby _["...insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_ inevitably leads to people posting answers with unjustified conclusions or unproven claims such as yours.   You can easily benchmark it.  _"I don't see how that affects execution speed"_ - everything has a cost even a compare and branch

Comment: I'm sorry if the word "pedantic" offended you, English is not my native language and I didn't think it has a negative tone.If my answer is wrong you should be able to easily disprove it. _everything has a cost even a compare and branch_ It doesn't have an execution cost if it doesn't run.

I agree with you that the question wasn't well suited for Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: Thanks, no worries then. :)  I've heard English is tough to learn.  Re benchmarks, the onus of providing proof is generally on _the person making the claims_ not the reader.     Imagine if you were a scientist claiming that he has finally invented cold fusion.  Whilst the general public will be greatly excited, other scientists will want to see your evidence/data so that they can replicate the claim and _how you arrived at your conclusion_. We're a bit like that :)  I would have loved to have seen your program output, timings, benchmarks maybe through great tools like Jetbrains dotTrace

Comment: _"compare and branch...doesn't have an execution cost if it doesn't run"_ - agreed but that's not quite what I meant sadly.  When [I did machine code](https://www.cocopedia.com/wiki/index.php/Xenion) I learnt that the program runs faster if you _unwind_ a `loop` and replace it with duplicated statements because the CPU cycle cost of `...CMPB 4 BNE BLTLOOP` represented a significant portion of my horizontal blit operation loop.  In other words _get rid of the comparison_.  And so in **Solution B** I think it would have been cool to know the cost to get to `FacingDirection.UP_RIGHT`

Comment: ...even though there are no loops to get there.  Anyway, we both agree about that the question wasn't suited for SO.  Have a good day :)  (BTW that cold fusion claim actually happened 15-20 years ago, was very embarrasing for the scientific world hehe :D )